# Specific times of day in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am writing an app where the user needs to book taxi but the booking time is 00:00 to 06:00 and 20:00 to 00:00.How do I show these timings on date picker for a single day?It could easily be done if there was a single time range,infact I have done that but what if there are 2 time ranges(this scenario)?

Comment: you can set one range like 20:00 to 6:00 as per your question. So your problem is solved

Comment: Can you elaborate?I can set minimum date and maximum date in UIDatePicker.So how can i set 2 ranges at once?